# Java : Convert an Inputstream string into file

Tags: java, file, inputstream, fileutils, ioutils

I am trying to write a String (read from an InputStream) into a file.
But when the output.pdf file is generated, it is corrupted.

In real-world scenario, I am receiving a string as an input from another service, from which I need to creat a file.
Hence, created a test code like below

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


File inFile = new File("test_input.pdf");
File outFile = new File("output.pdf");
InputStream inputStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(inFile);

// this String looks like:
// %PDF-1.4 ....

String s = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);

// Aim is to write the generated string as another file
// This is generating a corrupted file
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(outFile, IOUtils.toByteArray(s));
```

Comment: Are you aware that PDF files are not plain text? It is not correct to directly convert the contents of the stream to a `String`.

Comment: You are converting bytes to String and back which means they are translated according to some character set encoding and therefore unlikely to return the same value back. A pdf is a binary format, so your API is wrong if you pass PDF as String. Also, use `Files.copy`

Comment: And you're essentially copying a file, so `Files.copy` is all you need. btw, you can perform all your existing functionality without 3rd party libraries

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your InputStream has the contents of a valid PDF file, all you need is:

```
    Path outFile = Path.of("output.pdf");
    try (InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Path.of("test_input.pdf"))) {
        Files.copy(inputStream, outFile);
    }
```

These classes and methods are all standard Java API. There is no need to use any third-party library such as Apache.

The problem you were having was probably caused by the decoding of bytes from the input stream into a String followed by the encoding of the String into the bytes written to the file. This is not generally a lossless conversion, especially when the content is non-ASCII text. On the other hand, `Files.copy` transfers the content directly.